# Custom the downloaded file name and prevent number adding in js

Tags: javascript, html

I have following simple code for downloading file.

```js
let text = 'download'
function make(){
    const data = new Blob([text],{ type: 'type: "text/plain"' })
    document.querySelector('a').download = 'untitle'
    document.querySelector('a').href = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
}
make()
```

```html
<a download>Download</a>
```

Broswer (in chrome not sure about other broswer) will automatically specify the number for the second or more time of downloading a same name file.

Example:

first time download: untitle.text

second time download: untitle(1).text
......

Is it possible to prevent the browswer of this behavior from happening ?

Thanks

You could try in https://jsfiddle.net/yapb2xus/1/

Comment: What would you like to occur instead? Not permit the second download at all? Overwrite the first download with the second?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. What I am asking it that if it is possible to make every download (if the download name doesn't change) to have the same download name (untitle.txt) instead of untitle(1).text.....

Answer (score 0):

You just can't, that's the default behavior for most of the browsers and almost all OSes because you can't have two files with the same name.

Since chrome (and firefix I think) automatically save the file in a default path, in the first time the file `untitle.text` will not exist and will be saved with original name. At second attempt, the file will exist on default download path, so the browser automatically add a suffix to it.

What you can try is to create your own sequence, adding a timestamp or something else to the name at every click on the link.